# How to make a logarithmic axis in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How to make it happen? I'm using GnuPlot 4.6 version

[image: solution]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's something that comes up often!

```
set yrange[1e-4:1]
set logscale y
set ytics 1e-3, 10, 1
set format y "10^{%L}"
```